# Changing .csv delimiter on ADF

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure-data-factory, delimiter

I am trying to load a **.csv table** to **MS SQL Server** via **Azure Data Factory**, but I have a problem with the delimiter (**;**) since it appears as a character in some of the values included in some columns.
As a result, I get an error saying in the details "*found more columns than expected column count*".

Is there any way to change the delimiter directly on ADF before/while loading the .csv table (ex.: making it from ";" to "|||")?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't, because you can't distinguish between the column `;` and the delimiter. what you can do is add column qualifier in csv generation. Or update the file manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a problem with the delimiter (;) since it appears as a
> character in some of the values included in some columns.

As you have quoted that your delimiter is `;` but it is occurring as a character in some of the columns which means that there is no specific pattern of the occurrence. Hence, it is not possible in ADF.

The recommendation is to write a program using any preferred language (like python) which will iterate each row from the dataset and write a logic to replace the delimiter to `|||` or you can also remove the unrequired `;` and append the changes in new file. Later you can ingest this new file in ADF.